# Call gRPC Client Stub from External Django Application

Tags: django, client, grpc, stub

I'm following https://blog.codeship.com/using-grpc-in-python/ to use gRPC with Python. Has anyone used the client wrapper (client_wrapper.py ) with an external Django application? I need a way to call the client or client wrapper from an external Django application and obtain a stub to make the RPC calls. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you figure it out, stuck at same issue.

Comment: Harsh, it's been a while, but from what I remember, I did not figure this one out.